# get reference to a xlsx textbox

Tags: c#, excel-interop, xlsx

What is the way to get access to XLSX textbox object using c#? Currently I am trying the following code and got a COM exception.

```
Excel.OLEObject obj1 = (Excel.OLEObject)(worksheet.OLEObjects("myTextBox"));
MSForm.TextBox textBox = (MSForm.TextBox)(obj1.Object);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Used the following snippet:

```
Excel.Shape obj1 = (Excel.Shape)worksheet.Shapes.Item("myTextBox");
```

I was trying to set the text for this textbox. Did it using

```
 obj1.TextFrame.Characters().Text = "myText";
```